# Is it possible to install Linux as a standalone OS with a UEFI system that came preinstalled with Windows 8?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

I've tried installing Ubuntu several times as a standalone OS on my Toshiba Portege z935 which has a UEFI Bios and came pre-installed with windows 8 and it does not work. Is it really only possible to dual boot with Windows 8?

Comment: Yes is it possible. You said you previous attempts at installing failed. What happened exactly?

Comment: I would install Ubuntu and it would be successful. However after restarting it wouldn't boot. My hard drive was basically not being recognized.

Comment: GRUB. What method did you use to install. Something Else?

Comment: I just booted the live USB and installed the distribution to my hard disk following the prompts.

Comment: The Boot Loader should have been installed. Would you like me to create a Q&A where I go through the process of Installation for you?

Comment: If you can I would appreciate it.

Comment: Give me 7 mins. I will reply with a link to the quesiton.

Comment: Okay. I appreciate it.

Comment: Taking longer than I anticipated. You want to completely remove Win 8?

Comment: I'm sorry haha, I was waiting for you. And Yes. Windows 8 is already removed. The hard drive is empty.

Comment: Thanks. I'm coming through shortly How much Space is on the hard drive?

Comment: It is a Sold State Drive with about 120 GB of storage

Comment: last request: `sudo parted -l`from terminal  what's  the output for the SSD 120GB disk? paste output [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and paste link as reply.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8755886/

Comment: [see here for answer. Sorry for the long wait.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/543895/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-14-04-on-toshiba-portege-z935-using-something-else-qan/543896#543896)

Comment: But OP does not want to dual boot

Answer (score 3):

Fedora and Windows install a file called `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTx64.EFI` (`x64` is the architecture and can be something like `ARM` too) in the EFI System Partition (ESP) which allows to boot an application or operating system when the NVRAM entries (storage on the mainboard) to boot a certain OS are not available or missing. Ubuntu currently doesn't provide such a file, which results in a non-bootable installation in these cases.

You can follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/510172/40581) which install and configure Gummiboot for such scenarios. You can even [configure this for secure boot](https://askubuntu.com/a/520351/40581). [I already filed a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1366546), but it doesn't seem to get taken seriously.