# How Do I Install Ubuntu 14.04 on Toshiba Portege z935 Using Something Else?

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi

How do I Install Ubuntu 14.04 on Toshiba Portege z935 Using Something Else?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Boot up the CD/USB and go into live mode *(try without installing)*, when the computer has boot up, go to the terminal and enter `sudo parted -l` get to partition table for the disk you want to install ubuntu on with the disk space of roughly 128GB and make note of it.
(we will continue this process later on).

**Basic recommended install**

The most basic and recommended partitioning for a fully functional system, is a swap partition and a root partition **/** consuming the rest of the diskspace.

**More Advanced Install**

For this I will recommend;

[DiskSpace -The goal of this page is to offer advice and strategy on partitioning a Linux system.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)

After this, begin the installation process.

When the installation arrives at Installation Type screen, select `Something else`
[image: something else]

Now, on the next screen

Select the appropriate drive, the one you want to install the OS on with the 128GB or roughly estimated at 131072MB. This might be `/dev/sda`

[image: select-disk]

We are going to be creating three partitions. BIOS, / *(root)* and swap
Select create new partition table... (option in the bottom left)

[image: new partition table]

**Partition 1 bios_grub**

Select the free space and create the first partition which is the BIOS by clicking on the plus (+) button on the far left, horizontal to new partition table.

Your options for this partition should match the screen-shot below and click OK

[image: bios partition]

**Partition 2 swap**

Swap is a controversial topic. However the amount of swap should be given on the premises of whether of not you're gonna be hibernating your pc. If you are going to hibernate, swap should be the size of RAM else 4GB (4096MB) should be fine. Choose accordingly and OK again.

[image: swap-allocation]

**Partition 3 / (root)**

Basic: Give Root Partition Remaining Space

Advanced: Create a separate /home partition for personal files.

Recommended root for Disk Space available, 30GB
Give /home rest.

Follow snip below for root or alternate for /home partition

[image: root]

Select 128GB SSD to house boot loader
[image: grub]

Comment: This looks like you are setting up legacy boot on a GPT partitioned drive, you should mention this in your answer. I assume you have the same laptop where legacy boot is available in the UEFI settings and works for you (I have come across devices that don't have this feature anymore). A simpler method would be to [create a new MBR partition table](http://askubuntu.com/q/509006/40581) for such installations. I'd suggest posting this special case as *"GPT with legacy booting"* in http://askubuntu.com/q/343268/40581.